# Couchbase response | Node displaying data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, couchbase

I am new to Node/react but trying to connect to couchbase & get details using an id. I hit the API with postman and in console, I see the data, but also I see the below error:
Is there something I am doing wrong?
Test check 
_http_outgoing.js:485
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)

```
    var couchbase = require('couchbase');
exports.getMById = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req && req.params && req.params.id) {
    const getMByIdSuccCB = result => {
      console.log("Test check",result);
     res.json(result);
        };
    const getMByIdErrCB = error => {
      res.json(error);
    };
    getMById(getMByIdSuccCB, getMByIdErrCB);
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Bad Request' });
  }
  function getMById(successCB, errorCB) {
    try {
      const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://IP');
      cluster.authenticate("username", 'password');
      const bucket = cluster.openBucket('mybucket', function (err) {
        console.log("DB Connected");
        if (err) {
          console.error('Got error: %j', err);
        }
      });
      const N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
      const q = N1qlQuery.fromString(`SELECT * FROM mybucket WHERE IHGId = '${req.params.id}'`);
      const result = cluster.query(q, function (err, response) {
        console.log("Result:", response);
        //res.end(response);
       successCB(response);
      });
      console.log("result",result);
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      };
    }
    catch (Exception) {
      errorCB({ message: Exception, status: 500 });
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `res.json()` in getMById(successCB, errorCB) instead of exports.getMById.